# TCP IP Socket and Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am working on the following project: I created a TCP IP Client (WPF GUI) and a TCP IP Server (Python). The focus of this issue lies on the Server. At the moment I am able to send a message from the client to the server and the server gives a message back to the client.

The process and what I want to archieve:

- Client: Send eventbased message to the server (e.g. when a button
  status changed)
- Server: When the server received a message from the client, the
  server should continously send data to the client (e.g. send the
  current sensor value to the client per second). The server should
  also be able to react on new messages from the client and do some
  other stuff.

Issue:

- paralelle processes: the server waits for incoming messages and cant
  do anything else (data = conn.recv(1024)). So I am not able to send
  multiple messages back to the client.

My first idea was to use two threads:

1. Receive data from Client
2. Send multiple data to Client
3. MainLoop: Start threads, do other stuff

My question: Am I on the right way with using threads? I dont have much experience in TCP IP and using threads. Thank you for your help.

My current code for the server:

```
from threading import Thread
import socket
data ='' 
HOST ='192.168.0.108'   # Server IP or Hostname
PORT = 12345    # Pick an open Port (1000+ recommended), must match the client sport
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

def ReceiveAndSendData():
#managing error exception
    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error:
        print 'Bind failed '

    print 'Wait for connection'
    s.listen(5)
    (conn, addr) = s.accept()
    print 'Connected'

    # awaiting for message

    while True:
        print'start'
        try:
            print 'awaiting data from GUI'
            if not data: break
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print 'Received data: ' + data
            reply = 'Received data'
            conn.send(reply)
        except socket.error:
            print 'Connection lost'
            print 'Wait for connection'
            s.listen(5)
            (conn, addr) = s.accept()
            print 'Connected'
    conn.close() # Close connections



def Main():
    t1 = Thread(target=ReceiveAndSendData)
    t1.start()
    print 'DoSomething'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the current blocking methods or go async. I'd prefer the async method, but the blocking solution may be clearer for you, since you are new to TCP and threads. By the way, with async you need no additional threads and most actions will be handled by callbacks.

Blocking solution: You're right, 3 threads will be needed.

- 1: **Main thread**

  - Start the other threads, configs, console, data processing etc.
- 2: **Sender thread**

  - The threads just sits and listens to a synchronized queue. A synchronized queue is thread safe, so you need no other mutexes or locks. It won't cause deadlocks and other weird scenarios.
  - When a new packet (which is to be sent) gets queued, this threads will process it and keeps on processing the others (if there are) or just sits tight and waits for the next packet.
- 3: **Receiver thread**

  - When a number of bytes is available, you read the packet and pass it to its handler.
  - If the handler wants to send a packet back to the client, it puts the packet onto the synchronized queue and will be processed by the sender thread. The receiver thread will not hang and can continue receiving.

I suggest you keep on researching on the async TCP, it's nowadays definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. Now the server runs async..I used this code: https://pymotw.com/2/asyncore/#servers

Answer (score 0):

Threads will work or you can use non-blocking sockets. Have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

~Pat